# Mutating method sent to immutable object error with mutableCopy()

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray

In short after getting arrays from `NSUserDefaults` I'm getting `Mutating method sent to immutable object` error when I'm trying to change `NSMutableArray` value;

```
generalDone[self.todoTableView.selectedRow] = 1
```

When saving to `NSUserDefaults` I'm adding all `NSMutableArray`s to one `NSMutableArray`. Like;

```
var saveArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
saveArray.removeAllObjects()
saveArray.add(generalTodos)
..
..
..
saveArray.add(generalDone)
UserDefaults.standard.set(saveArray, forKey: "test3")
```

But when I'm getting arrays from NSUserDefault I'm sure it is a mutableCopy().

```
if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "test3") != nil {
    saveArray = UserDefaults.standard.mutableArrayValue(forKey: "test3").mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray

    generalTodos = saveArray[0] as! NSMutableArray
    generalDone = saveArray[1] as! NSMutableArray
}
```

Still getting same error. Maybe silly idea but I'm thinking arrays in saveArrays still not mutable. But don't know how to manage them. What's your ideas?

Trying to learn swift. Please be polite. -_-

Comment: May I ask why you are using NSArray / NSMutableArray at all? They are Objective-C Cocoa classes. You should be using _Swift_ arrays. They make things much easier.

Comment: "but I'm thinking arrays in saveArrays still not mutable" Good thinking. You may be making a mutable copy of `saveArrays` but that doesn't make the arrays inside it mutable.

Comment: Also I would advise against saving an array of arrays into NSUserDefaults. Just save `generalTodos` as its own array with its own key.

Comment: Finally, note please that UserDefaults is very picky about what you can save into it. You can save an array of strings, but not, say, an array of ToDoObjects. So watch out for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use Objective-C NSMutableArray, saying `as! NSMutableArray` won't make one; the way to make an NSMutableArray is to say

```
let mutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: otherArray)
```

But you should be using Swift arrays, not Objective-C NSArray/NSMutableArray. To make a Swift array mutable, declare it with `var`, not `let`. For example, if `generalTodos` is an array of strings, you could say

```
var generalTodos = [String]()
```